# how to convert word document to pdf using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert Word files to PDF programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607669/how-do-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-programmatically)

how to convert word document to pdf using vb.net using a free component like pdfsharp or itextsharp...

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537063/itextsharp-convert-word-doc-docx-to-pdf

Comment: Did you not notice the related questions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the documentation first, eg http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpSamples.ashx, and ask a more specific question if you have trouble.

Comment: pdfsharp does not do any kind of conversion