# SOAP web service to convert docx to pdf

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, docx

Can someone point me to a existing SOAP web service that can be used to convert docx file to a pdf file. To be more precise, I'm looking for "up and running" web service that I can use in my project to do this conversion.

Comment: Did Google have any results? What about searching existing questions?

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't find any workigng solutions for this

Comment: If you haven't already seen these, these 2 seem almost identical (resolved) questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333459/ and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537063/

Comment: Hi Richard, indeed these two questions are similar to mine, but not the same, and unfortunately neither of them provide the solution.

Comment: how about create your own web services by using itextsharp or the others?

Answer (score 0):

Gnostice [XtremeDocumentStudio .NET](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=270&t=Converting_From_DOCX_To_PDF_Using_XtremeDocumentStudio_NET) can convert docx to PDF but it is not web service. You will have to write that on your own. Disclaimer: I work for Gnostice.