# Any tool to convert word and excel to PDF?

Tags: pdf, interop, ms-word

Is there any SDK available to convert MS word and Excel files to PDF ? I wan to do it on Web Server at run time. Im using VS 2010, .Net Framewrok 4.0
I looked into MS interop assembly but then this artical pushed me back http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

is there any thirdparty tool/SDK/Service available that will do that at runtime?

Comment: Related; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537063/itextsharp-convert-word-doc-docx-to-pdf (not mentioned is doc->html->pdf which itextsharp can do.

Answer (score 0):

Check out iText, there is a Java and C# library however I think the .NET library is not free.  http://www.itextpdf.com/

Comment: iText does not convert word and Excel to PDF

Comment: Java version is not free either (both versions are AGPL-ed).

Answer (score 0):

If you are after perfect conversion then there is no real solution available / viable other than somehow involving Office. Plain MS-Interop is a nightmare and very unreliable, but there are good third party solutions available.

Give the [Muhimbi PDF Converter Services](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services/summary.aspx) a look. It installs in your environment as a scalable and robust Windows Service and has specifically been designed for use from server based applications such as ASP.NET.

It comes with a [friendly web services based interface](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html) that allows it to be used from most modern environments such as Java and .NET. It supports all common as well as some not so common file formats. [Watermarking](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/06/using-awesome-new-watermarking-features.html) and PDF Security is included as well. If you have SharePoint in your environment then a [SharePoint optimised version](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx) is available as well.

Disclaimer, I have worked on this product so the usual disclaimers apply. Having said that, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Save as function which is already available in Microsoft.Office.Interop

```
doc.SaveAs(ref FileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
```