# Export file to PDF

Tags: vb.net, itext, export-to-pdf

I'm using iTextSharp component for VB 2010.  I am importing image files and office files from the user and converting the imported file into a byteArray.  How do I use iTextSharp to export the scanned or imported file to PDF? Can anyone help or direct me to the proper example?

Comment: Perhaps this could be of assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537063/itextsharp-convert-word-doc-docx-to-pdf

Comment: I see...so iTextSharp will not let me take a byteArray that represents an imported Word file to PDF, which is not good...but what about an image file that is already in a byteArray??